# How do I use res.partner ORM to create a Partner Registration functionality

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, openerp-7, openerp-8

I am currently learning how to use odoo (Using version 8), I am developing a Fuel management system. I noticed there is a `module` called **fleet** which I can conveniently use. I would like to add partners in the fleet module so that a user can `register new partners`, how do I achieve this? I was thinking to create a separate module named partners but there is ORM model named `res.partners` how can I use it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem after spending almost the whole day going through a couple of odoo resources.

I only had to edit `fleet_view.xml` which is located at `addons/fleet/` 
I added a form,menu item and window action as follows:

**Added Form* with window action*

```
<record model='ir.actions.act_window' id='fleet_partner_act'>
    <field name="name">Partners</field>
    <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
      <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
        Click to create a new vehicle.
      </p><p>
        You will be able to manage your fleet by keeping track of the
        contracts, services, fixed and recurring costs, odometers and
        fuel logs associated to each vehicle.
    </p><p>
        Odoo will warn you when services or contract have to be
        renewed.
      </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

**Created Menu and Refer our Action here**

```
<menuitem name="Partners" parent="menu_root" id="fleet_partners" sequence="4" groups="group_fleet_user"/>
```

`<menuitem action="fleet_partner_act" parent="fleet_partners" id="fleet_vehicle_menu" groups="group_fleet_user"/`>